# Multiple headings allowed inside html section element?

Tags: html

The textbook use of the section html tag is to include a heading element and a paragraph element. Is it permissible to include two headings in one section element, e.g. h2 headings, and two paragraphs, one under each heading?

Comment: Are you still unclear about this? Did the answer below answer your question?

Comment: Hi Chris, yes thank you. What I ended up doing was to put a section element around each h2 element & associated paragraph and subsections, and then a section element around each subsection like h3 and associated paragraph, etc. So nested section elements. For the h1 element, I already had a main element in place on each page, so if there was an image and paragraph under the h1, I put just them in a section element and not the h1 element. I assume this is best practice in such circumstances (opinion I know!)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is permissible to include multiple headings inside one section element.

Sections [may contain flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section#technical_summary), and [headings are a type of flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content). Note that [this may create more sections than you expect](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#heading-content) (emphasis added):

> The first element of [heading content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#heading-content) in an element of [sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#sectioning-content) [represents](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/rendering.html#represents) the heading for that section. *Subsequent headings of equal or higher [rank](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/sections.html#rank) start new (implied) sections, headings of lower [rank](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/sections.html#rank) start implied subsections that are part of the previous one.* In both cases, the element [represents](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/rendering.html#represents) the heading of the implied section.